# Google Sheets: Average of largest values in each row of an array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, average

I have an array 3 columns wide x 10 rows deep. Each row contains at least one number. I need a formula that takes the average of the largest numbers in each row.

I can easily do this by adding a 4th column and dragging the Large function down, then averaging that column, but I would like to avoid that if at all possible.

My demo sheet is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T13CCF_RVxVeY9PfNGSiEh-g-OB2dukbBEpvRaMmXkY/edit?usp=sharing

What formula can go in G2 that can calculate the value in G1 without needing Column D? (You can ignore all the text values in the array, they're irrelevant)

Comment: You must show your own effort to post. Try my answer below.

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr; That sheet was my attempt; I didn't want to leave any junk formulae sitting around. For the record, I did try - a lot, but couldn't even come up with a bad example to list here. I only just learned of the Large function, and kept trying to figure ways to work something like Average(ArrayFormula(Large([range],1))), but for the life of me couldn't get anything to work. I read through probably a dozen posts on here and explainers on Average, AverageIf, AverageIfs, Large, Max, ArrayFormula, MaxIfs, Index, and Match, but couldn't come up with a solution, nor anything close.

Comment: That is rule of this site. This site works on trial and error basis, so we appreciate to post faulty formula so that we can correct it. Read this article. https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/find-max-value-in-each-row-in-google-sheets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula. See your sheet.

```
=query(
     transpose(
        query(
           transpose(ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:C),A2:C,""))),
           "Select "&REGEXREPLACE(join("",ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A),
           "Max(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&"),",""))), ".\z","")&""
        )
     ),"Select avg(Col2) label avg(Col2) ''"
)
```

[image]